# SALVAR IMAGEM VARBINARY EM BANCO DE DADOS

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Olá,
tenho uma aplicação windows form, já tenho um botão para fazer o upload via FileDialog para a minha picture box, exibindo-a.
Segue o código

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files(*.png)|*.png|AllFiles(*.*)|*.*";

        if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string foto = dialog.FileName.ToString();
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = foto;
        }

    }
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como eu consigo salvar no meu banco de dados sql essa imagem que está nessa picture box, usando um outro botão, pois eu tenho 4 colunas VARBINARY, e quero fazer o upload de cada uma por vez e depois salvar tudo em um " cadastro " só. 
Segue a imagem do formulário para entenderem minha ideia.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém saberia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1):

Antes de por um exemplo de como fazer isso deixo algumas considerações que você deve ter em conta antes de avançar para essa abordagem. E como em tudo na vida não é facil dicidir.

**Escolha esse caminho se:**

- Você está armazenando imagens que vão mudar dinamicamente
- Necessidade legal de manter um arquivo durante um período de tempo.
- Imagens guardadas no banco de dados não requerem uma estratégia de backup.
- É mais fácil controlar o acesso às mesmas.

**Não opte por esse caminho se**

- Exigir código adicional para mapear a imagem em disco com o identificador do banco de dados
- A latência pode ser mais lenta que o acesso direto a arquivos
- A Carga no servidor e tempo de resposta for critico.
- Não tenha restrição à capacidade de storage. No caso de não existir controle no tamanho das imagens.

Exmplo de como fazer isso:

```
private void Save()
{
    string sourcefilePath = @"C:\temp\foto.jpg";
    string storageFilePath = @"C:\storage\";
    string cnString = @"Integrated Security = SSPI; Initial Catalog = <Your Data Base>; Data Source = <server>";
    string uniqueidentifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnString))
    {
        string command = $"INSERT INTO Images VALUES ('{uniqueidentifier}', '{sourcefilePath}')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        File.Copy(sourcefilePath, Path.Combine(storageFilePath, uniqueidentifier) + ".jpg");

    }
```

Comment: Minha necessidade nessa aplicação é : salvar as imagens e depois recuperalas no banco em algum formato ( tanto jpeg como png ).

Comment: Resposta atualizada com exemplo

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo um exemplo ainda não testado, porém com o código necessário para converter a imagem do controle PictureBox e salvar em uma tabela no Banco Sql server. Faça sua adaptação para suportar a gravação de mais de uma imagem. No exemplo abaixo considerei a imagem no formato Jpeg.

```
string nomeFoto;
string connectionString;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.Filter = "JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files(*.png)|*.png|AllFiles(*.*)|*.*";

            if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string foto = dialog.FileName.ToString();
                nomeFoto = foto;
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = foto;

            }

        }

     //Handle do botão Enviar para salvar uma imagem na Tabela CadastroFoto.
     // (Adaptar para as 4 imagens que você quer salvar)
    private void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         byte[] fotoByte = ImageJpegToByte(pictureBox1.Image);
         using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
         {
            // Comando insert
             SqlCommand addImageCmd= new SqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO CadastroFoto("+
                    "Nome, Imagem) "+
                    "VALUES(@Nome, @Imagem)",connection );

            addImageCmd.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = nomeFoto;
            addImageCmd.Parameters.Add("@Imagem", SqlDbType.Image, fotoByte.Length).Value = fotoByte;

            //Abre a conexão e faz o INSERT do registro no banco
            addImageCmd.Connection.Open();
            addImageCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
    }

    //Método para conversão de uma imagem .Jpeg para um array de bytes
    public byte[] ImageJpegToByte(System.Drawing.Image img)
    { 
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
       img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
       byte[] img = ms.ToArray();
       return img;
    }
```